# Companion matrix, polynomial

Tags: matrices, companion-matrices

I have the following polynomial

$$p(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + t^3$$

and the following information

Let $p$ be indicated as above. Suppose $\lambda$ is a real root in the polynomials p, in other words, λ is a real eigenvalue for C. Let Eλ be the corresponding space for C;  then $ Eλ = {x∈Rn | Cx = λx}$

I have been given three questions

(i) Define the Companion matrix for the polynomial above.

The first question is answered which corresponds to the matrix bellow

$ C_p=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\quad\\
0 & 0 & 1\quad\\ 
-a_0 & -a_1 & -a_2\quad\\
\end{bmatrix}$

(ii)  Show that $\quad$
 $  v_λ =\begin{bmatrix}
1\\\
λ^2\\ 
λ^3\\
\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for C which belongs to λ

That question is answered to0. Since λ is a zero of p, then $ a_0 + a_1λ+ a_2λ^2 +λ^3$ and $ -a_0 -a_1λ -a_2λ^2 = λ^3 $ gives us

$  C_p =\begin{bmatrix}
1\\\
λ^2\\ 
λ^3\\
\end{bmatrix}$ = $ =\begin{bmatrix}
λ\\\
λ^2\\ 
-a_0 -a_1λ - a_2λ^2\\
\end{bmatrix}$ = $  =\begin{bmatrix}
λ\\\
λ^2\\ 
λ^3\\
\end{bmatrix}$

That is $C_p(1,λ,λ^2) = λ(1,λ,λ^2)$ which shows that $(1,λ,λ)$ is an eigenvector of C_p corresponding to the eigenvalue λ $

(iii) Explain that $E_λ =Span (v_λ)$ and therefore $ dim E_λ = 1$

How do I solve the last question using what I have done so far?